# SQL Server 2008 R2 has wrong default collation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When I installed SQL Server initially, my computer region was set to ENGLISH (UNITED STATES). I think this made the default collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. The production server and my colleague's SQL Server setups have `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

I changed my region to match theirs as ENGLISH (Australia) and I uninstalled SQL Server 2008 and deleted the databases. I then reinstalled, but it's still `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` for collation.

I've now reinstalled several times, and I can't have my default collation set to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Does anyone know how to change this? Where when installing does it let you choose your collation?

Answer (score 3):

```
setup.exe /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /QUIET /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER 
          /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" 
          /SQLCOLLATION=Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: This worked but the Microsoft Documentation was wrong. It said to use the setup.exe in the Setup Bootstrap/Release folder but it only works if you use the Setup Bootstrap/SQLServer2008R2 folder...